# Alternative implementation of Expected<T>

Tags: c++

Recently I have watched a [presentation about "Systematic Error Handling in C++"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C) given by Andrei Alexandrescu. The structure of the proposed Expected template is as follows:

```
template<class T> class Expected {
    union {
        T ham;
        std::exception_ptr spam;
    };
    bool gotHam;
};
```

Using union make the implementation a bit complicated as you need to branch by `gotHam` field and *then* decide how to handle data in the union. I.e. initialization on initialization list cannot be done for `ham` and `spam`.

I wonder if a simplified version would make it better.

```
template<class T> class Expected {
    union { T ham; };
    std::exception_ptr spam;
};
```

In this case `spam` can be used as an indicator whenever an error has occurred.

Comment: The `union` in your version makes no sense…

Comment: I think the `union` will prevent an execution of a default constructor of `T`.

Comment: You still need to branch but now you need to test if spam is a null pointer. There's no difference.

Comment: std::exception_ptr is more than just a pointer since it keeps the exception alive (more like a shared_ptr) so your Expected is the size of T + some type of smart pointer rather than max(T, std::shared_ptr) + bool. In addition std::exception_ptr is not guaranteed to be constexpr which means your Expected can't reliably be constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pointer on ham, that way the default constructor isn't called and you don't need the union which doesn't really make sense in your version.

Also, i don't think your version changes the need to branch, since you still have to test the exception pointer rather than the boolean.

Answer (score 1):

My comment rewritten as an answer:

Your version has a few issues:

- Instead of `sizeof(Expected) == max(sizeof(T), sizeof(std::exception_ptr)) + sizeof(bool)` you have `sizeof(Expected) == sizeof(T) + sizeof(std::exception_ptr)`. Since std::exception_ptr is more like a smart pointer rather than a normal pointer it could be significantly larger.
- std::exception_ptr is not guaranteed to be constexpr and you always have to construct it. That means Expected cannot be constexpr and still be portable.

For all the downsides you still have to switch on the exception pointer which is no less complicated than the bool.